# How to limit pylint checks to current repo defined objects only?

Tags: python, coding-style, pylint

I have a repo containing mostly tests which is later combined with hardware "API" repo to create a test environment. Problem is the API repo uses its own coding standard, which results in pylint errors when functions defined in it are used in test's repo.

I could use good-names option of pylint to whitelists all the objects names, but it seems dirty. Is there any way to whitelist those based on origin of object?

Answer (score 1):

What about ordering *pylint* to ignore the Python modules coming from this external *API* instead? I believe something like this should be possible thanks to the `ignored-modules` option. See [pylint's "Typecheck checker Options"](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html#typecheck-checker-options).

So maybe add a `.pylintrc` file containing something like this:

```
[TYPECHECK]                                                                     
ignored-modules=apipackage
```